# Can't choose anything but "Save file" for PDF files in Firefox

Tags: firefox, adobe-reader

At some point my Firefox stopped showing PDF files in the browser. Instead, when I click a link to a pdf, it instantly jumps to the Save As prompt. I am reading about how to change that:

### What it is supposed to look like:

According to [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-without-downloading-them#w_using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer)

[image]

### What it looks like in my Firefox:

[image]

Translations:

- Spørg altid = Always ask
- Gem filen = Save file
- Vælg en anden = Use other

Where is Preview in Firefox?

Even if I choose Adobe Reader, then restarts Firefox, it still jumps directly to Save As, when I try to open a PDF file.

I tried installing Adobe Reader over, but just the a notification that it was already installed.

Firefox is version 29.0.1. Adobe Reader is version 11.0.6. The Adobe plugin is 11.0.6.70.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should uninstall Adobe Reader then install it.  That is the only way you can make sure you solved the problem.  At the very least you eliminate Adobe Reader as the problem.

Comment: What if click on "General"(Generelt) tab, and set radio button on "Save filese to..."? Instead "Always ask me where to save file".

Comment: Are you asking what will happen?  It will always download the file to the download directory.  `Preview in Firefox` will use Firefox ability to view PDF files clearly.

Comment: Today I had the same problem. In my case it was a solution.